# My loop in JavaScript gets progressively slower while updating the page's DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, electron

My Electron app contains a page which runs a loop within a JavaScript file. The loop updates every 600 milliseconds using setTimeout. The code works perfectly fine while adding values to a text area within the pages DOM, but slows down progressively by about 2-3 milliseconds every 5 seconds when I use JavaScript to update the text area scroll height. Using Chrome Dev Tools doesn't indicate a memory leak on first glance.

Does anybody know why that specific change to the DOM worsens performance progressively but the other change doesn't and how I could possible rectify the issue?

Example of the code:

```
const log = document.getElementById('log-text');

function start() {

    /// do stuff

    core()

    }

    function core() {

        /// do stuff

        log.value += "Looping..."; /// this does not appear to affect performance
        log.scrollTop = log.scrollHeight /// adding this line progressively worsens performance

        // do stuff

        coreTimer = setTimeout(core, 600);

    }
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier If anyone knows why that specific change to the DOM affects performance progressively but the other change doesn't and how I could possible rectify the issue.

Comment: In what way does it affect the performance?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Without that line, it takes about 602 milliseconds to complete the core function including the timeout each iteration. When I add the line that resets the scroll height, it progressively increases each iteration (ex. 602ms, 605ms, 607ms, 610ms).